# How to make controller opencart function

Tags: opencart

I have this script for making subdomain and I want to placed it in the opencart contoller. How to do that and how to make it work with the insert function?

```
$cpanel_user = 'root';
$cpanel_pass = 'password';
$cpanel_skin = 'x2';
$cpanel_host = 'yourdomain.com';
$subdomain = 'mysubdomain';
$dir = 'public_html/mysubdomain';

$sock = fsockopen($cpanel_host,2082);
if(!$sock) {
  print('Socket error');
  exit();
}

$pass = base64_encode("$cpanel_user:$cpanel_pass");
$in = "GET /frontend/$cpanel_skin/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=$cpanel_host&domain=$subdomain&dir=$dir\r\n";

$in .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$in .= "Host:$cpanel_host\r\n";
$in .= "Authorization: Basic $pass\r\n";
$in .= "\r\n";

fputs($sock, $in);
while (!feof($sock)) {
$result .= fgets ($sock,128);
}

fclose($sock);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? I dont get it. Please explain your problem more detailed.

Comment: this is a php code for make a sub domain and I want to place it in opencart controller. I've tried to make protected function subDomain() and placed the code as it is but it dont work. I think opencart has it own way to write there code.Can you help?

Comment: Why would you want to make a subdomain in OpenCart? What for?